# How To run Coded UI Test method from from Unit Test project where selenium web driver is used

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have created a unit test project with Selenium to perform some UI actions. In one of page i need to upload file from local machine,  and for that  i am using SendKey method available in c# but that is not consistent so i thought if  we can add a small recorded coded UI method which would just do windows interaction like select file from window control. I browse through MSDN and tried all links but its not happening. Please help me in this regards

say I have created a Unit test Project "Test" and inside that created  a Unit Test class added selenium web driver references and inside it a Test Method in which i  launched the  browser and  reached till the point where i need to upload file.

Now I added a coded UI test file and recorded the uploading the file part in CodeUITestMethod1() in new class CodedUITest.

Now when i try to call codedUITestMethod1() from my first test class its giving  errors like "PlayBack.dll "or "UITest.dll" or some other Dll could not be Found. But i have added all the coded UI and these dlls and i ensure that i call PlayBack.Initilize() before codedUITestMethod1() is called but everytime i get some errors at PlayBack.Initilize() method.

I have taken refrence from follwing links :

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gautamg/2010/03/30/how-to-get-uitesting-methods-working-outside-the-testmethod-of-coded-ui-test/

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/07/15/running-codedui-test-from-another-application/

I have used visual studio 2013 for this work . Pleas Help

Comment: Why isn't the send keys consistent? I've never had a problem with it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Send keys are not consistent  with my application being run in VM. out of 10,  6 times it fails. moreover i saw a link where someone has already done it. "http://stackoverflow.com/users/54288/aligned" but i could not with same way. I felt posting here i will definitely get some help

Comment: Alright, you added the .dlls but are you sure they're being copied to the test deployment directory? I've had problems with this before. At the top of the test class if you put [DeploymentItem("PlayBack.dll"), DeploymentItem("UITest.dll"), ... etc ] does it still say the .dlls can not be found?

Comment: Hello Parker, yes .dlls are getting copied to the bin folder but it did not work. i did not put Deploymentitem attribute. will try with that approch. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hello Parker, after another attempt what i observed that one of the dependent assembly is not being copied to the output directory, i copied the assembly and gave a try  and it worked fine. Thanks  very much for your help.